# Is there a way to invite a user to chat

Tags: discussion, support, chat

Is there a way where I can invite a user to a chat room instead of doing back and forth sometimes to resolve an issue? SFSE pops the chat invitation only when a certain number of comments are posted on the thread. Earlier there used to be a salesforce room, I cannot see it anymore.

How do I create a new session and invite a user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Salesforce room is at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4337/salesforce , it was frozen due to lack of activity, but I just thawed it. Invite folks in to talk there!

I asked in the moderators' forum, and apparently only StackOverflow really has the volume to support per-question rooms. If we all use the Salesforce room, it will stay active and appear on the Chat link.

Comment: Thanks metadaddy.