# Is there a way to Invite an user to a chat room

Tags: discussion

I had previous asked about inviting an user to a chat group:

[Is there a way to invite a user to chat](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/569/is-there-a-way-to-invite-a-user-to-chat)

Extending this I saw that stackoverflow has a way of inviting an user who is already part of a chat room, is there a way to send a message to the user to join on chat (@ mentions sometime do the trick but mostly I do not see @{!user_name} bringing in the user)

[Inviting a user to chat from the profile page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126100/inviting-a-user-to-chat-from-the-profile-page)

Comment: rao, would you please test this on me to see if it shows up in my message feed by making a comment in the chat room to @crmprogdev? Curious minds & such...

Comment: @crmprogdev just did :) a test message from chat, you should have 2 messages show up in your notifications, if @ mention works from chat

Comment: Unfortunately, I only saw this message. :(

Comment: yep until you are in the chat room (I don't think it matters which room you are in, but you should be atleast in one of the rooms) the @mentions don't work.

Comment: Was a useful exercise to confirm where it works *and*  and *does work* plus to discover how difficult it can be to **find the relocated chat link** in our new interface!